# iOS Swift - Efficient way to design HTML-like Table

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

I am fairly new to iOS Swift Development and I am currently designing UI for my mobile application and the goal is to produce something similar to HTML Table with header on the left and content on the right like follows:

[image]

Currently I have achieved it by using multiple Stack Views and stacking it against one another in the following manners:

[image]

However this has caused my **Xcode** to be very slow (I assume it is caused by stacking too many things and it uses memory).

Therefore I would like to know whether **there are other more efficient ways to achieve the same result (produce the same design).**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `this has caused my debugger to be very slow`even mean? Have you run the Time Profiler to determine and measure the cause of any "slowness" in your app? I would be very surprised indeed if a few `UIStackView`s caused your app to be slow and I don't understand at all how `UIStackView`s would cause the debugger to be slow.

Comment: Sorry if I made you misunderstood what I tried to meant. What I meant was because of this arrangement it made my Xcode slow.
The "debugger" above meant my "Xcode"

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use tableview? Add two labels in each cell on left size and right side. Set the style of cell to right detail if you want to use the default configuration.